# How can I download all usernames?

Tags: linux, users

I have access to a university's Linux server where all students have accounts. I can retrieve their full name by typing the `finger username`, and their departments by typing `id username`. All the student usernames are consecutive. For example:

```
e205846
e205847
e205848
e205849
e205850
...
```

Is it possible for me to write a some kind of script and retrieve all the information to some kind of database? Or is there already an available tool for that? Also, as side note there some www folders in the Linux which has all the usernames.

Here is one example

```
e147290@beluga:~$ finger e204158
Login: e204158                          Name: april oneil
Directory: /home705/e204158             Shell: /bin/bash
Never logged in.
No mail.
No Plan.

e147290@beluga:~$ id e204159
uid=53653(e204158) gid=5621(ce_bs) groups=5621(ce_bs)
```

Comment: Can you list each of the fields you need from that output? E.G `$user, $uid, $gid, $name`. Some of that information will need a lookup outside of /etc/passwd.

Comment: @mtm, I cannot list them separately.

Comment: If there is a legitimate reason for you to gather all those names, ask the admins.

Comment: `getent passwd` might work.

Comment: @ilhan You can't list the fields that you want to collect into this database?? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, `getent passwd` prints out around few 100-200 acounts' information, out of 48500 accounts.

Comment: @mtm, ough, sorry, now I get what you, sorry my English is poor. I want to collect the full name and department given that I know the username. In the example above they are: april oneil, and ce_bs given that username is e204158.

Comment: Edit. I'll test the hard ones tomorrow. Like using C or loopers etc. And I'll report back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux systems there's the `getent` program, which utilizes the standard `get*ent(2)` functions (`getpwent()` being the one to use here).  What you want to retrieve are the contents of the `passwd` database (try `man nsswitch.conf` for a further understanding):

```
$ getent passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
sashroot:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:65004:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:65005:65060:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:65006:65012:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:65007:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:65008:65008:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
...
```

It gets a lot more interesting after the standard system accounts scrolled by.

If you're not an a Linux system, you can get this rather easy by writing something that dumps the user database on its own by using the `getpwent(2)` function.  An example in C would be something like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    struct passwd *pwd;

    while ((pwd = getpwent()) != NULL) {
        printf("user = `%s', uid = %d, gid = %d, name = `%s'\n",
               pwd->pw_name, pwd->pw_uid, pwd->pw_gid, pwd->pw_gecos);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Put this in a file `test.c` and build it with

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
```

Then you can call `./test` and look what you get:

```
$ ./test
user = `root', uid = 0, gid = 0, name = `root'
user = `sashroot', uid = 0, gid = 0, name = `root'
user = `daemon', uid = 1, gid = 1, name = `daemon'
user = `bin', uid = 2, gid = 2, name = `bin'
user = `sys', uid = 3, gid = 3, name = `sys'
user = `sync', uid = 65004, gid = 65534, name = `sync'
user = `games', uid = 65005, gid = 65060, name = `games'
user = `man', uid = 65006, gid = 65012, name = `man'
user = `lp', uid = 65007, gid = 7, name = `lp'
user = `mail', uid = 65008, gid = 65008, name = `mail'
...
```

As above, it'll get more interesting later on.

The approach of using `getwent()` has the big advantage that you don't have to make any assumptions on how the login system is configured (`/etc/passwd`, LDAP, NIS, …?) but just let the system retrieve the information with its actual configuration.

**Edit:** It might happen that the `passwd` database's storage backend, e.g. LDAP, doesn't permit enumerating the database (and thus `getpwent()`) but only hand you out data sets explicitly requested by key (e.g. login name or UID, so `getpwuid()` or `getpwnam()` might work).  In this case (and since your target user names are so neatly named) you could still "enumerate" manually with a modification of @masegaloeh's script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {000000..999999}; do 
    getent passwd "e${i}" 2> /dev/null
done
```

How to do this in absence of `getent` with the system API (`getpwnam()`, `getpwuid()`) is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: It might be useful to use Python instead of C. You have access to low-level C libraries but data manipulation is much easier.

Comment: It is not homework. There is a new foreign very hot female student (I'm foreign student too, anyway), I don't know her name. So, instead of manually checking the last 5000 accounts I thought that it would be better to build a database, check the last 7000 accounts, sort them by unique given names (like where a given name appears only once), and then concentrate on the departments in the Business Administration building. Then it would be easy to spot her. Plus, I'll check her name on Facebook. Nothing serious, I won't message or talk to her. I'm just curious. She is 11/10. :)

Comment: The account database may not always be _enumeratable_, so `getent` (or getpwent), even when available may not always work.

Comment: When would you not be able to enumerate it @StephaneChazelas?

Comment: @ilhan seriously? Sometimes Unix is not the answer. Put the laptop down, say "Hi, My name's ..."

Comment: @mtm: With LDAP as backend, for example, you could deactivate enumeration (a.k.a. `search`) but tell LDAP to only give out records explicitely requested (by login or UID, for example).  In this case, »enumerating« (by hand) over the user names via `getpwnam()` would work, `getpwent()` won't.

Comment: I have used this code https://gist.github.com/ilhanyumer/8380741028c924c8d0d0

Answer (score 5):

getent is indeed the right way to access any database through the name switch on a Unix/Linux system, so it doesn't matter if accounts are stored locally in /etc/passwd, or if they are in LDAP, AD, NIS, or whatever service you have configured in nsswitch.conf.

So I'd do:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$1 ~"^e[0-9]*$" {print $5}'
```

This will print the full usernames for all accounts beginning with 'e' and followed by only digits.

If I needed to do this on a Windows system, I'd install cygwin and then do it as above :). In fact I just tested getent on Windows/cygwin and it works great (somewhat surprisingly).

Comment: Prints out 62 accounts' full names out of 48500 accounts.

Comment: @ilhan: Can you tell if just "getent passwd" generates all the expected user accounts? Do they all consist of the letter 'e' followed by only digits? That was my understanding, and is what the awk pattern is designed to match.

Comment: `getent passwd` prints out many (not all) accounts such as `e146178:x:6207:2191:benek celjina:/home705/e146178:/bin/bash
` which includes the username (e146178), full name (benek celjina), department (2191) which corresponds to gene_bs. Some of them were like `wwwecon:x:21698:20000:ekonomi toplulugu:/homewww/wwwecon:/bin/tcsh` https://gist.github.com/anonymous/de59bb84bdc8404c9cc0 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/15885f3798e64fb95c41

Comment: Student numbers are given in sequence order. My username number is e147200. Now, the last username is somewhere around e201000. Some usernames do not exist to trap email spammers. Some users are like michaeljackson if they are professors, or some users are like wwwstat (Statistics Department web server) if they are department web servers.

Answer (score 3):

This bash script will do looping for you

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {205846..205850}; do
    finger e${i}
    id e${i}
done
```

You just modify 205846 and 205850 to get different range

Answer (score 1):

/etc/password output is your safest bet as finger will print duplicates if some part of the name matches.

The following bash script should do the trick, it'll output
user $output of id user

```
l=$(grep "^UID_MIN" /etc/login.defs)

# get max UID limit
#l1=$(grep "^UID_MAX" /etc/login.defs)

# if not set, set manually
l1=4999

# get all users and assign to users array
users=$(awk -F':' -v "min=${l##UID_MIN}" -v "max=${l1##UID_MAX}" '{ if ( $3 >= min && $3 <= max ) print $0}' /etc/passwd | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ":" } ; { print $1 }')

# print the needed info
for user in $users ; do echo -n $user && echo -n " " && id $user ; done
```

If you change the last line to

```
for user in $users ; do echo "INSERT INTO users(name,groups) VALUES('$user', '`id $user`');" ; done
```

It'll get you SQL insert statements, e.g

```
INSERT INTO users(name,groups) VALUES('priit', 'uid=1056(priit) gid=1056(priit) grupid=1056(priit)');
```

Comment: If you use `getent passwd` instead of `/etc/passwd` you will get users from other databases as well (eg. LDAP or NIS)

Comment: @mtak `s/will/might/`, those database may not necessarily be _enumeratable_.

Answer (score -3):

You can get all user information from /etc/passwd

Comment: This is without much doubt plain wrong on every larger scale network, like the ones in a university and if it was done with `/etc/passwd` UNIX accounts the system operators would be either incredibly bored or just insane beyond belief.  NIS/YP exists for at least 30 years.

Comment: @AndreasWiese Yes. I agree with you. :)